# How to use a travis.yml file without commiting

Tags: travis-ci

In order to test your travis.yml file, which especially when setting it up for the first time could take a few iterations, you always need to commit the file. This produces quite a few unecessary commits.

Is is possible to test a yaml configuration file without commiting the file? Like some option in the web interface to restart a build with a modified travis.yml.

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but you can of course always just delete the commits afterwards.